# Sharepoint pagination

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, pagination

I'm trying create client-side pagination using Sharepoint Rest Api, i use $skip and $top parameters:

```
http://siteurl/_api/lists/getByTitle(list name)/items?$skip=0&$top=2
```

But with:

```
http://siteurl/_api/lists/getByTitle(list name)/items?$skip=2&$top=2
```

I have the same result as a first link

I know about __next url in response, but i need back and forwerd pagination between pages

Does anyone have usecases for solving this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Currently `$skip` query option is not supported in SharePoint 2013/Online.

According to [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](http://Use%20OData%20query%20operations%20in%20SharePoint%20REST%20requests):

> The `$skip` query option does not work with queries for SharePoint
>   **list items**.

There are several options for implementing client-side pagination using SharePoint REST Interface.

### Option 1

Utilize `$skiptoken` query option to return paged results

Format:  `$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=<last item id to skip>&$top=<items count>`

**Example**

The example demonstrates how to retrieve the limited count of items (2 items) with id equals or greater to `2`  from `Pages` library:

```
function getPagedItems(webUrl,listTitle,startItemId,itemsCount)
{
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle +  "')/items?$skiptoken=" + encodeURIComponent('Paged=TRUE&p_SortBehavior=0&p_ID=' + (startItemId-1) + '&$top=' + itemsCount);
    return executeRequest(endpointUrl,'GET');
}


getPagedItems('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/','Pages',2,2)
.done(function(data){
    if(data.d.results.length == 0){
        console.log('Items not found');
        return;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++){
        var item = data.d.results[i];
        console.log(item.Title);
    }   
});
```

where

```
function executeRequest(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    if (typeof headers == 'undefined'){
        headers = {};
    }
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if(method == "POST") {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

### Option 2

Utilize SharePoint **2010** REST interface to retrieve paged results using `$skip` query option:

Endpoint example: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Pages?$skip=2&$top=2`

Comment: i am using same request url  but i am getting probelm when like here you r getting 2 data and  skip 2 data  if in list have 3 data then  when call again it skip first 2 item and give 3rd item but it also give me first item also.

Comment: please see my question.http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192228/when-few-items-available-in-custom-list-then-skiptoken-give-repeated-items

Comment: Is there anyway to get the all the data without having pagination?